# Sci-fi book about future of earth where the land has been submerged, and aliens use it to breed

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

1970's or 80's book about the future earth.

Aliens invaded, and sunk the land, now there are floating islands, and the aliens come back every so many years to plant eggs in the sea to hatch.

There are mer-people as well as normal humans.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This could use a few more details; you should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: From the description it sounds like it could be a duplicate of the following:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123907/1970s-book-about-a-flooded-earth-by-aliens-floating-cities-and-pirates-that-pa/123910#123910   You can find more information about the book at:  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2348455.Conquerors_from_the_Darkness

Comment: It sounds rather a lot like John Wyndham's *The Kraken Wakes* (1954). It has alien invaders inhabiting the seas and breeding, and sea levels rise because the aliens melt the poles. The land, however, is not reduced to islands, though a lot of major cities (including London) are flooded. Nor are there any mer-perople.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kraken_Wakes

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155918/earth-as-water-world-invasion-at-climax-fought-off

Answer (score 2):

This is *Conquerors from the Darkness* by Robert Silverberg.

> A thousand years in the future, the earth has been conquered by an alien race and covered by a single sea. Dovirr Stargan, who is disgusted with the servility of his life on the floating city of Vythain, longs to become one of the Sea-Lords, who roam the sea as powerful protectors of the cities. Dovirr gets his wish, but the return of the alien race brings unexpected and critically dangerous crises to his new life as he learns the real, sometimes terrible, significance of power. 
>   
> <sub>[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2348455.Conquerors_from_the_Darkness)</sub>

Comment: Exactly, thanks, this is the one I was searching for.

Comment: Hi, Steven! As this is obviously the correct answer (you wrote it to your own question), please accept it with the checkmark to mark this question as answered. Thanks!